# Find duplicate element in a list of lists

Tags: python, duplicates, nested-lists

I am looking for Python ideas for the following problem.

Given a list of lists...

```
[[20, 21, 22], [17, 18, 19, 20], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

If there is a duplicate element that is common between any or all the lists, return True. If all of the elements are unique, return False.

In the example above, 20 is common and would return True. The example below would return False because all the numbers are unique between the lists.

```
[[20, 21, 22], [17, 18, 19], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
```

Lastly, testing for duplicates in an individual list is not needed because the numbers are always sequential.

FYI - this problem will be used to optimize an airline crew members monthly schedule. Each list represents a 3, 4, or 5 day airline trips that can't overlap.

BTW - this problem is not an assignment but a personal quest to work less and get paid more :) Sorry it was unclear. I tried a brute force method which works but was hoping for a more elegant Pythonic method. I appreciate all the responses as they are leading me into new areas of Python programming.

Comment: You mean in common between any two lists, not in common between all lists?

Comment: For a one-liner that you won't understand and your teacher will fail you on if this is an assignment that you haven't tried to do any work on: `return Counter(chain.from_iterable(ll)).most_common(1)[0][1] > 1`.

Comment: @abarnert But for...[[20,20],[],[]] this returns true o.0

Comment: @Shashank: OK, if that's valid input `return Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(set, ll))).most_common(1)[0][1] > 1`. (If I were a teacher who'd given this assignment, your question would be a great way to test if they understood their own answer…)

Comment: @abarnert Now that's an A+ answer. :)

Comment: Someone is just spamming downvotes in here.

Comment: @jgritty stay in the comments section bro, you'll be safe here 8)

Comment: @abarnert `most_common()` would also work.

Comment: @StefanPochmann: Sure, but that builds a list of all of the values that we don't actually need, so why bother?

Comment: @abarnert Because it saves a character :-P And don't say that's inefficient... collecting all duplicates rather than stopping at the first duplicate is inefficient anyway.

Comment: @abarnert But thanks, you made me think of the in hindsight obvious solution: `max(Counter(chain.from_iterable(ll)).values()) > 1`

Comment: @StefanPochmann: I never say "that's inefficient" unless someone writes a cubic solution to an inherently linear problem or something (or the OP specifically asks about efficiency and seems to actually mean it). It just feels Veruca Salt-ish to ask for everything even though you can't even use it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a *specific* target (your question was unclear):

```
def find_dupe(lists, target):
    seen = set()
    for lst in lists:
        for item in lst:
            if item == target and item in seen:
                return True
            seen.add(item)
```

DEMO:

```
>>> find_dupe([[20, 21, 22], [17, 18, 19, 20], [10, 11, 12, 13]],
              20)
True
```

If you're not, then you can simply strip out the `item == target` condition

```
def find_dupe(lists):
    seen = set()
    for lst in lists:
        for item in lst:
            if item in seen:
                yield item
            seen.add(item)
```

Comment: edited the question to be more clear. Your code works with the 'item == target' stripped out and with return True

Answer (score 3):

```
num = Counter(i for j in alist for i in j) # flatten list into a single dimension
dup = [k for k, v in num.items() if v > 1] # checks the dict for duplicate values
```

Comment: I don't know, but this is a good answer so +1 :) or voting limit reached. :(

Comment: +1. Not a big fan of combining the lists through `reduce(operator.add, ...)` but I think that's mostly personal preference. I prefer `[item for sublst in lists for item in sublst]`

Comment: @AdamSmith Advice taken into consideration.

Comment: Maybe downvoted because it doesn't *"return True or False"*?

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to forgo the elegance of list comprehension, you could do the following:

```
seen, dups = set(), set()
for l in ll:
    dups = dups.union(seen.intersection(set(l)))
    seen = seen.union(set(l))
```

Your answer should be in `dups`.

**Edit**

As [Steven Rumbalski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1322401/steven-rumbalski) pointed out below, the `set` inside the `set`-member operations' arguments, is redundant (and needlessly expensive).

Comment: No it won't. That will only contain elements that are found in _all_ sets, which does not include `20` in his example. (Also, you could simplify this whole thing to just `dups = set.intersection(*map(set, ll))` if it actually were the right answer.)

Comment: @abarnet Thanks for the correction. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> list_of_list = [[20, 21, 22], [17, 18, 19, 20], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
>>> counts = Counter(item for sublist in list_of_list for item in sublist)
>>> repeated_items = [item for item, count in counts.items() if count > 1]
>>> repeated_items
[20]
```

Comment: Fair enough, let's remove this chat.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
l = [[20, 21, 22], [17, 18, 19, 20], [10, 11, 12, 13]]
dupes = []
flat = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
for f in flat:
    if flat.count(f) > 1:
        if f not in dupes:
            dupes.append(f)

if dupes:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Aiming for efficiency here.

```
def duplicates_exist(ll):
    seen = set()
    see = seen.add
    for l in ll:
        for element in set(l):
            if element in seen:
                return True
            see(element)
    return False
```

[@Stefan Pochmann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30471344/2653390) made me realize that I had an unnecessary generator earlier. >_<

Comment: Wow, that `see = seen.add` is truly beautiful!

Comment: @StefanPochmann It could possibly be taken further to form constructs like `seen = seen.__contains__` so containment could be tested like `if seen(element)` but IMO anything that requires double underscores is something to be avoided beautywise.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> any(element in seen or seen.add(element)
        for lst in lists for element in set(lst))
True
```

I only use `set(lst)` instead of just `lst` because it's not clear whether a sublist can contain duplicates.

As hinted at by @Shashank, this is efficient as it stops at the first found duplicate (just like [Shashank's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30471304/1672429)). If there are many sublists but there's a duplicate in the first two, then the remaining ones won't even be looked at. It's thus faster than solutions that first collect all duplicates from everywhere and then turn that into a boolean only afterwards.

**Update:** @abarnert's comment made me think of this:

```
>>> max(Counter(chain.from_iterable(ll)).values()) > 1
True
```

Or shorter (but slower):

```
>>> max(Counter(sum(lists, [])).values()) > 1
True
```

These two don't handle duplicates inside a single sublist, but I find it reasonable to assume that that can't happen, as otherwise the specification should really say so or at the very least the example should have one.

Comment: @Shashank Thanks, fixed. And also made it the requested boolean.

Comment: @Shashank Although quite frankly, if a sublist can contain duplicates, then the specification should say so and the example should have one.

Comment: Beautiful! Yours is a more compact version of mine. +1

Comment: Oooh. I didn't even realize that efficiency aspect. Thanks :-)

Comment: `ll` has to be mapped to set first for that `chain.from_iterable` solution. :p I'm also pretty sure that `Counter.most_common(1)` is more efficient than using `max` but I could be wrong!

Comment: @Shashank Argh, not that again. Don't want to "fix" this, especially if it's not necessary, so I added a remark about it. Thanks for pointing it out again.

Comment: @Shashank No, `most_common(1)` is probably slower than `max`. I checked, it'll do this: `_heapq.nlargest(1, self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1))`

Comment: Isn't peeking at the top of a max heap (O(1)) much faster than linear time O(n) max algorithm?

Comment: @Shashank That would be faster, yes. But the Counter doesn't keep a heap around. You can see it gives all `self.items()` to `nlargest`, which then goes through all those key/count pairs. And in a complicated way as well.

Comment: Wow seriously? Then why the heck doesn't Counter have `least_common` method too? -_- It would be trivial with `heapq.nsmallest`. I thought the whole reason for it *only* having `most_common` was because it was keeping a max heap in the background.

Comment: @Shashank Excellent question :-). And I just did a test with `c = Counter(range(1000000))`. For `max(c.values())` it took 0.6 seconds, for `c.most_common(1)` it took 2.7 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me..All this time I thought `most_common` was using a pre-built max-heap or something like that. That's just dumb that it doesn't provide `least_common` as well.

Comment: @Shashank Building a heap is O(n log n), though, while building a Counter ought to be O(n) like dict. In many cases (like this one right here) you don't need to use `most_common` and thus wouldn't want that extra O(log n). Anyway, I saw that there's even a [`least_common` patch](http://bugs.python.org/issue16994) but it hasn't been accepted in 2+ years.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to try this:

```
def find_dup(listOfLists):
   for index in range(len(listOfLists) - 1)
      result = [filter(lambda x: x in listOfLists[index], otherLists) for otherLists in listOfLists[index+1:]]
      if result:
          return True
   return False
```

The idea is to look at the first list (listOfLists[0]) and check if any of its elements is repeated among the other lists (listOfLists[1:]), in the affirmative case return True, in the negative one, take a look to the second list (listOfLists[1]) and take again a look to the other lists (listOfLists[2:]) and so on. It's important to avoid checking every time from the begining.

I could not test this example, but I think it should work :).

Hope this help.